# JQuery AJAX file upload responseText is not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a jQuery/AJAX script for file uploading and I handle the upload with PHP. It works perfectly with a progress bar and validations. There is one issue however, I cannot get any response text that I have set in PHP and encoded it using `json_encode();`, but don't get any response and get this instead:

```
<div class="upload-div">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload_form" >
      <label for="file" id="file_label" class="file-label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> إضافة صور<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple="" accept="image/*" /></label>
      <input type="submit" id="upload_files" name="submitUpload" value="رفع الصور" />
      </form>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="status-message"></div>
      <div class="images-previews"></div>
      <div id="next_step"></div>
    <span class="submit-buttons">
    <a href="form" class="url-color"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> الرجوع</a>
    <form method="post"><input type="submit" name="submitNoPics" value="التقدم بدون صورة" /></form>
    </span>
  </div>

  <script src="js/upload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

  {"message":"Successfully uploaded 1 files!"}
```

As you can see the message I want to display is on the last line of code but it doesn't show alone. It shows with the whole HTML document. I will post my HTML and PHP code below, because I am new to Ajax and I am struggling. Please help me if you can and explain because I don't just want to get it done, I want to actually understand how and why this is not working. Thank you.

PHP:

```
  <?php
  //file upload

  $extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
  $dir = 'user-uploads/';
  $count = 0;
  $imgCounter = 1;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files'])){
      for($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++){
        unlink('user-uploads/img'.$listingID.'-'.$x.'.jpg');
        unlink('user-uploads/img'.$listingID.'-'.$x.'.png');
        unlink('user-uploads/img'.$listingID.'-'.$x.'.gif');
      }
      mysqli_query($connectionDB, "DELETE FROM ad_image_tbl WHERE ad_id = $listingID");
      // loop all files
      foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name ){
        // if file not uploaded then skip it
        if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
          continue;

        /* skip unprotected files
        if( !in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions) )
          continue;
        */
          switch($_FILES['files']['type'][$i]){
            case 'image/jpeg' : $ext = '.jpg'; break;
            case 'image/png' : $ext = '.png'; break;
            case 'image/gif' : $ext = '.gif'; break;
            default : $ext = '';
          }

          if($ext == ''){
            echo errorMessage('<li>الملف المرفق لا يعتبر صورة</li>');
            $error_message = 'الملف المرفق لا يعتبر صورة';
            $message = array('message'=>'Attached file is not a valid image file.');
            exit();
          }
          else{
        // now we can move uploaded files
        if($count <= 7 ){
          $listingImage = $dir.'img'.$listingID.'-'.$imgCounter.$ext;
          if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $listingImage))
          mysqli_query($connectionDB, "INSERT INTO ad_image_tbl VALUES('$imgCounter', '$listingID', '$listingImage')");
          $imgCounter++;
          $count++;
      }
    }


    }
          $message = array('message'=>'Successfully uploaded '.$count.' files!');
          echo json_encode($message);
  }

   ?>
```

jQuery/AJAX:

```
    $(function() {
  /* variables */
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
  var fileCount = fileInput.files.length;
  if(fileCount > 8){
    fileCount = 8;
  }
  var bar = $('.bar');
  var progress = $('.progress');

  /* submit form with ajax request using jQuery.form plugin */
  $('.upload_form').ajaxForm({

    /* set data type json */
    dataType:'JSON',

    /* reset before submitting */
    beforeSend: function() {
      bar.width('0%');
      progress.css('display', 'block');
    },

    /* progress bar call back*/
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(pVel);
    },

    /* complete call back */
    complete: function(message){
    //  var responseMessage = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    progress.css('display', 'none');
    document.getElementById('next_step').innerHTML = '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="uploadSubmit" value="الانتهاء" /></form>';
    console.log(message)
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: it's too hard to create a overview of this whole code... could you tell us what the result is, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Hello @Hallur . The result is the whole document with a JSON object right at the bottom containing the message I want to display. The result I want to achieve is that the ajax displays the message alone without the whole HTML code.

Comment: Usually when you use ajax to submit a form, for example. The returned result will be the entire output of the call. Meaning if the website you're posting to. Have you considered splitting the submit form and the result into two different files?

Comment: @Hallur I have done it and split the code. The upload handling code is now in a file called 'upload_handling.php' and I have set the action attribute to point to it. And it still shows me the whole HTML document but now without the message..

Answer (score 0):

Why could you use a plugin to handle upload.
[dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

You can get response as below

```
$(function() {
    Dropzone.options.uiDZResume = {
        success: function(file, response){
            alert(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hello, I am nearly done with my upload, all I really want to achieve now is the responseText!